# Search and replace a word in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this -

```
str = 'some_random_command_that_take_parameters -d{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3", "tableName": "my_table", "key5": "value5", "key6":"value6"}'
```

I need to search "tableName": "my_table" and replace it with "tableName": "my_table_temp" in python.

The value "my_table" is variable and I dont know it while codeing. So I can not just search it and replace. The only thing I can search for sure is "tableName" (or any other key).

Edit:
Sorry for not being clear, the example is not a dictionary, the whole thing is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a string:

```
s = '{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2", "key3": "value3",' + \
    ' "tableName": "my_table", "key5": "value5", "key6":"value6"}'

# using regular expressions
#   (quick and dirty)

import re
s = re.sub(
    '(?<="tableName":)\s*"(.*?)"',
    lambda match: ' "{}_temp"'.format(match.group(1)),
    s
)


# OR


# using ast.literal_eval
#   (less efficient but more bomb-proof)

import ast
d = ast.literal_eval(s)                     # parse to dict
d["tableName"] = d["tableName"] + "_temp"   # update field
s = str(d)                                  # cast back to string
```